# Angular JS - Using {{}} in script

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm very new with Angular so don't even know if what I'm trying to do is the right thing here. If not, please point me in the right direction.

**What I want to do:**

I'm using JSON to get external map data as well as [angular-google-maps](http://nlaplante.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api) to load in data. My JSON has about 100 places, with names, latitudes and longitudes. I want to use Angular to loop through that data and place markers on my map for each place.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
  <li class="places" ng-repeat="place in places">
      <p class="link">{{place.name}}</p>
      <p>{{place.lat}}</p>
      <p>{{place.lng}}</p>

  <div class="google-map" 
    center="centerProperty"
    zoom="zoomProperty" 
    markers="markersProperty"
    latitude="clickedLatitudeProperty"
    longitude="clickedLongitudeProperty"
    mark-click="true"
    draggable="true"
    style="height: 500px; width: 80%; ">
  </div>
</li>

</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
(function () {
    var module = angular.module("angular-google-maps-example", ["google-maps"]);
}());

function ExampleController ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('json/map-data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.places = data;
  });

    angular.extend($scope, {

        /** the initial center of the map */
        centerProperty: {
            lat: 45,
            lng: -73
        },

        /** the initial zoom level of the map */
        zoomProperty: 8,

        /** list of markers to put in the map */
        markersProperty: [ {
                latitude: 45,
                longitude: -74
            }],

        // These 2 properties will be set when clicking on the map
        clickedLatitudeProperty: null,  
        clickedLongitudeProperty: null,
    });
}
```

**Why it's not working**

Obviously I'm a little over my head, I'm TRYING to find a way to get `{{place.lat}}` and `{{place.lng}}`into the `markersProperty:` in the Javascript. Can I somehow push these values into the markersProperty array? What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In your JavaScript, reference them through $scope:

```
$scope.place.name
$scope.place.lat
$scope.place.lng
```